# 404 Page not found in laravel

Tags: laravel, routes

I'm trying to add a new page in laravel. I've checked the index page, controller and I keep getting a 404 error.

web.php

```
Route::group(
    ['namespace' => 'Admin', 'prefix' => 'admin', 'as' => 'admin.', 'middleware' => ['role:admin']],
    function () {
Route::group(
        ['middleware' => ['licence-expire']],
        function () {    
Route::resource('curriculum', 'AdminCurriculumController');
```

Controller

```
public function index()
{
    $this->curriculum =Curriculum::count();
    return view('admin.curriculum.index', $this->data);
}
```

Comment: What is the URL you are calling? It has nothing to do with your concrete issue, but in the `index()` function, you are storing `$this->curriculum` but you return `$this->data`, which seems odd. Best is to avoid storing data in class variables in controllers anyway. In other words, use something like this. `public function index() { $count = Curriculum::count(); return view('admin.curriculum.index', compact('count')); }`

Comment: Thanks so much for your response. This is the URL I call localhost/admin/curriculum  and I get the 404

Answer (score 1):

By using `prefix` all routes in the group get the `admin/` prefix. The `curriculum` resource can then be found at `localhost/admin/curriculum/`. You can list all available routes by issuing `php artisan route:list`

If the route doesn't show up in `php artisan route:list` try clearing the cache: `php artisan route:clear`. If this doesn't work try adding a test url to ensure the cache is cleared:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your response. That is exactly what I do and it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you add the result of the `php artisan route:list` command? @SimonaBuga

Comment: that route does seem to register, here is how the other routes look like

Comment: |        | GET|HEAD  | admin/products                                                                                               | admin.products.index                                        | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\AdminProductController@index                                      | web,auth,role:admin,licence-expire,Closure

Comment: How did you configure your local environment? Did you use wamp? Could you try starting your project with `php artisan serve` and retry the `admin/products` url? @SimonaBuga

Comment: all other web pages are displaying when I run php artisan serve, with the exception of the curriculum, like I said even when I look at the web routes it doesn't pull it, yet it pulls all other routes. Is there another place where I might need to register a web route?

Comment: All routes in web.php should be shown by the route:list command. Could you try running the following command: `php artisan route:clear` @SimonaBuga

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

You have probably cached your routes, so you can't add any more because Laravel will now be based on the cached file and not on the web.php file you are updating